# I can't get shopping cart Icon to appear in emulator for my homework assignment

Tags: java, android

I'm on step 3.3 to create this app from this webpage: 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-clickable-images/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#4

Everything seems correct and so I go to run the app on an emulator but the shopping cart icon doesn't appear on the bottom of the app.

I re-checked the code and it matches the solution code. I have no idea why orderActivity isn't running on the emulator.

solution code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Inflates the menu, and adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     *
     * @param menu Menu to inflate.
     * @return Returns true if the menu inflated.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles app bar item clicks.
     *
     * @param item Item clicked.
     * @return True if one of the defined items was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // This comment suppresses the Android Studio warning about simplifying
        // the return statements.
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a Toast with the message.
     *
     * @param message Message to display
     */
    public void displayToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows a message that the donut image was clicked.
     */
    public void showDonutOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.donut_order_message));
    }

    /**
     * Shows a message that the ice cream sandwich image was clicked.
     */
    public void showIceCreamOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.ice_cream_order_message));
    }

    /**
     * Shows a message that the froyo image was clicked.
     */
    public void showFroyoOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.froyo_order_message));
    }

}
```

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void displayToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void showDonutOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.donut_order_message));
    }

    public void showIceCreamOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.ice_cream_order_message));
    }

    public void showFroyoOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(getString(R.string.froyo_order_message));
    }
}
```

no error messages, the shopping cart icon doesn't appear on the emulator.

Comment: [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/blob/3064cf5aa8f248122a951757b071282d8ef44b50/DroidCafe/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L42) should have a `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: THIS one?<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />